# Show a custom component / html on NextJS App Router Error Handling in a data fetch

Tags: next.js

I am intentionally generate an error through my API Fetch:

**src/App.tsx**

```
....imports

async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/usdtbalance", {
    cache: "no-store",
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
     return {};
  }

  return res.json();
}

export default async function Home() {
    const data = await getData();
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<p>Fast component loading...</p>}>
            <p> {data.balance}</p>
        </Suspense>
 )}
```

I did understand that there is a error.tsx which will show an Error Component when an error occurs. But I do not want that my whole page is not working because a single API call failed.

But instead of showing a whole new Error page, I want that my:

```
<p> {data.balance} </p>
```

is just showing something like:

```
<p> Data could not be fetched! </p>
```

How can I create a custom error message for a single variable and now show the whole error.tsx page?